# trying to use include in lambda getting an error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I am trying to query the comments that has relationship with request table like this below

```
public class Request
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public Correspondence Correspondence { get; set; }
    public MasterSection MasterSection { get; set; }
    public RequestStatus RequestStatus { get; set; }
    public RequestStage RequestStage { get; set; }
    public RequestType RequestType { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my class for correspondence class  below

```
 public class Comment
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string CommentBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
public class Correspondence
{
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();
}
```

and here is my linq query to get the results

```
 public IQueryable<Request> GetAllRequests()
 {
        return _dbContext.Requests.Include(i =>i.RequestStage)                                 
                                  .Include(i =>i.RequestType)
                                  .Include(i =>i.MasterSection)
                                  .Include(i=> i.Correspondence).ThenInclude(i=> i.Comments);

  }
```

but getting an error like `Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.` with out including correspondence, the above query is working is fine but when i included the correspondence getting above error.

Is there any other way to get all those related data along with correspondence for the requests

I am using EF core 3.0

Could any one have any idea why i am getting this error and any idea how to overcome this error that would be very grateful to me.

Thanks in advance

sample data

[image]

Comment: Instead of `.ThenInclude` have you tried chaining `.Include("Correspondence.Comments")`?

Comment: i tries getting the same error that i was mentioned in the question `return _dbContext.Requests.Include(i => i.RequestStage)
                                      .Include(i => i.RequestType)
                                      .Include(i => i.MasterSection)
                                      .Include(i => i.Correspondence)                                  
                                      .Include("Correspondence.Comment")`

Comment: Can use share the mapping class of this classes?

Comment: i already shared above in the question about request object with the correspondence class and i am using code first approach, please let me know if you need more info

Comment: @LuttiCoelho please let me know if you need anymore info

Comment: How is the class related to the table structure? Is `Correspondence` in a separate table?

Comment: sorry for confusion, there is no table correspondence it is just json blob storage that will be in request table, i will add data for request table above and we are using postgres sql with EFCore 3.0

Comment: If it's a blob field in the Request table itself you don't need to use `Include`. Include is for loading related entities.

Comment: yup got it thanks..

Comment: @vendettamit please add your comment as an answer. It will help others users too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments of Question, `correspondence` is a blob field in the `request` table itself you don't need to use Include. 
Include is for loading related entities.